# Dalvikvm - Unable to resolve static field [Noclassdeferror] - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently trying to load a class from another project, but it gives me this error in run-time and not compile time:

```
VFY: unable to resolve static field 840 (Read) in Lshared/TestingMode;

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shared.TestingMode
```

And this is the class :

```
public enum TestingMode {
Read,
Write}
```

I have imported the projects and fixed the Java Build Path so there are no compile errors.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352215/java-why-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-static-field-initializ-failur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead creating enum, create a public class, its members are in public static final variables and access it from class name.

Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822906/603233

Comment: Alright thanks a lot that works, what about "unable to resolve static method" ?